# pywin32 running 32bit windows service on 64bit OS

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32

I am running 32bit python application on old Windows Server 2003 using pywin32 package and it's working fine. Lately I've received new Server with windows Server 2012 64bit OS and I started installing the same application. While it didn't run under 64bit Python 3.4 I've installed 32bit version and it's working fine when I am running it from command line.

The problem starts when I want to run it as windows service. It installs and looks ok but it doesn't start.
I am receiving following error: The service is not responding to the control function.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186.

When I check pythonservice.exe it shows me following error:
PythonService was unable to locate the service manager. Please see the event log for details

Is there any way I could run it as it does run under 32bit?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Where did you download Python 3.4 **64-bit**? ActiveState version? It doesn't contain pyWin32 extensions by default. Just install it manually from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/

Comment: I've installed Python 3.4 64-bit from main website and then installed pyWin32 in 64-bit version as well but one of the components of my application doesn't work under 64-bit so I've reinstalled Python and pyWin32 to 32-bit version. Python itself seems to work as I can run application crom command prompt but I can't start installed service